# Stabilization through nonnegative control

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I will have to work on a project about stabilization through nonnegative control. I got some articles about it, which mainly talk about controllability. But, why do we even want stabilization through nonnegative control?

$$\dot{x} = Ax+Bu$$

I know it means that input $u$ is positive, but why do we want this $u$ to be positive?

Hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: Think of a rocket with a single thruster. The input is sign-constrained. No brakes!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the quantity of an antibiotic or other drug that is given to a patient, or or the dose of radiation that is given.